# Вернуть $.ajax data в return функции

Tags: jquery, ajax, javascript

Есть аякс запрос в функции

```
function Check_production(order_number){
var result = false;

$.ajax({
   url: "load/check_production.php",
   cache: false,
   async: false,
   data: {zakaz_number:zakaz_number}, 
   type: 'POST',
   success: function(data){
        if (data == "true"){
            result = true;
        }else {
            result = false;
        }
   }
 });

return result;
```

}

Можно ли сделать более красиво без отключения асинхронного запроса / локальной переменной / каким либо еще способом, чтобы Check_production вернула result?

Comment: нет нельзя, ибо  на то он и асинхронный запрос. надо описывать через callback, типа 

    function Check_production(order_number,callback){
        //...
        callback(result);  //вместо ретурн
        //либо
        //callback(order_number,result);
    }

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Посмотрите в сторону объекта Deferred, пример с ajax:

```
function SomethingInit(id){

    this.init = function(id) {
        // Загрузка с сервера информации
        this.load(id).done(function() {
           // ... здесь продолжается инициализация ... 
          alert("продолжаем после успешного запроса");
        }).fail(function(message) {
          alert('ошибка..')
        });
    };

    this.load=function(teamId){
        var dfr = $.Deferred();
        alert('посылаем запрос');
        $.ajax({
                url: 'load/check_production.php',
                success: function(response, status, jqXHR){ dfr.resolve();},
                error: function(jqXHR, status, error) { dfr.reject() ; }
        });
        return dfr; //dfr.promise();
    };

    this.init();

};
```

Также существует ряд библиотек-оберток для этого объекта, мне в свое время приглянулась JSDeferred: http://habrahabr.ru/post/108575/